# Xquery : querying xml with key value pair in t-sql

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql, xquery-update

In the below code block  I'm able to query till DataElements.
for below xml

```
DECLARE @xmlString XML;
SELECT @xmlString='<Activity xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActivityCode>570</ActivityCode>
  <ActivityId>0011d966-fa28-440c-9196-5dbe3c40b2ac</ActivityId>
  <CreateDateTime>2014-06-19T06:57:46.9854126-04:00</CreateDateTime>
  <DataElements xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:KeyValueOfstringDataElementLjh4bohd>
      <a:Key>AgentId</a:Key>
      <a:Value>
        <DataType>String</DataType>
        <Name>AgentId</Name>
        <Value>abc\xyxaa</Value>
      </a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringDataElementLjh4bohd>
    <a:KeyValueOfstringDataElementLjh4bohd>
      <a:Key>PhoneCallStartTime</a:Key>
      <a:Value>
        <DataType>String</DataType>
        <Name>PhoneCallStartTime</Name>
        <Value>06/19/2014 10:57:47</Value>
      </a:Value>
    </a:KeyValueOfstringDataElementLjh4bohd>
  </DataElements>
</Activity
```

>
below XQery

```
SELECT @xmlString.query('for $activity in /Activity
let $activityId := $activity/DataElements

return data($activityId)
') AS [activityId]
GO
```

is giving me the result:

```
AgentIdStringAgentIdabc\xyxaaPhoneCallStartTimeStringPhoneCallStartTime06/19/2014 10:57:47
```

But what I want is if I pass AgentId , I should get abc\xyxaa   and if I pass PhoneCallStartTime, I should get 06/19/2014 10:57:47. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use predicates and axis steps to select and filter the results. Similar to the code you used:

```
for $activity in /Activity
return data($activity/DataElements//a:Value[Name="PhoneCallStartTime"]/Value)
```

There is a namespace involved here. You either have to

- declare the namespace `a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays` or
- ignore the namespace of the element and use the wildcard namespace operator `*:` instead of `a:` for the `Value` element.